# --no-site-packages with Apache mod_wsgi

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, virtualenv

I installed Django 1.5 to a virtual enviroment created with --no-site-packages option.

Although site-packges path of virtualenv is added to ystem path in wsgi file, Apache ignores the Django1.5 and uses Django 1.3 (installed to global python library previously)

What may cause this problem and how can I resolve it?
You can find my django.wsgi file below and I can provide any neccessary information.

**django.wsgi**

```
import os
import sys
import site

vepath = '/home/myuser/projects/myenviron/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
site.addsitedir(vepath)


sys.path.append('/home/myuser/projects/')
sys.path.append('/home/myuser/projects/myproject/')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be using a quite old version of virtualenv as the --no-site-packages option is deprecated these days as it is the default. Thus you shouldn't need to be explicitly providing it.

Anyway, read:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments

Better still, use mod_wsgi daemon mode and the python-home option.

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ChangesInVersion0304